# How To Slow Speed Of Recorded Audio Visualization In Android?

Tags: java, android, audio

How To Slow Speed Of Recorded Audio Visualization In Android ?

I am able to record the voice from mic and play the recorded audio with visualization, 
But the speed of visualization is to fast, how can i slow the speed of visualization.
Below code is used to draw the visualization in android..

```
public class VisualizerView1 extends View {

    private byte[] mBytes;
    private float[] mPoints;
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();
    private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

    public VisualizerView1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init1();
    }

    private void init1() {
        mBytes = null;
        mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
        mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mForePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 128));
    }

    public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mBytes == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
        }
        mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2 + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2 + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
        }
        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is hard to read without proper indentation but I don't see your actual update loop? For memory purposes you should also add an empty background style and avoid using invalidate() instead of invalidate(Rectangle) or it will invalidate and redraw invisible components as well.

Comment: Visualization is working fine, i am able to see Visualization of  current audio playing, but the speed is to fast how to slow the visualization or assigning current pitch by vertical line on Visualization..

Comment: Wherever the draw is executed in your code you can probably set a number of updates per second.

Comment: i didnt get what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with some visualizer code where i just "skip" every second frame. Maybe this is what was you were looking for at the time.

I added a boolean, then just tests if this is true, and simply skip the code if not

```
private boolean frameSkip = false;


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    if(frameSkip)
    {
        frameSkip = false;
    }
    else
    {
        frameSkip = true;
        ...Your code here
    }
    canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
}
```